# Filter is preventing to reset table values

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

The two main components in my jsf are  p:tree and p:dataTable

The idea is to create a table according to the tree node selection.

Jsf:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%" columnClasses="treeColumn,tableColumn">
        <h:panelGroup id="treePanel">
            <p:tree id="tree" 
                    value="#{genRepBean.root}" 
                    var="node" 
                    dynamic="true" 
                    cache="true" 
                    animate="true"
                    selectionMode="single"
                    selection="#{genRepBean.selectedNode}"
                    rendered="#{genRepBean.renderTree}"> 
                <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{genRepBean.onNodeSelect}" update=":mainForm:tablePanel"/>
                <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open"  
                            collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" styleClass="tableTreeText"/>  
                </p:treeNode> 
                <p:treeNode type="au" icon="ui-icon-document">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />  
                </p:treeNode>  
            </p:tree> 
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="tablePanel">
            <p:dataTable id="acqDataTable"
                         var="acq"
                         value="#{genRepBean.acqList}" 
                         rendered="#{genRepBean.renderTable}"
                         filteredValue="#{genRepBean.filteredAcqList}"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorPosition="bottom"
                         paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                         rows="10"
                         lazy="false"
                         style="width: 100%">
                <p:column headerText="ID" sortBy="#{acq.Id}" styleClass="tableTreeText"> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{acq.Id}" />  
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="IP ADDRESS" sortBy="#{acq.ipAddress}" styleClass="tableTreeText">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{acq.ipAddress}"/>  
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="STEP" sortBy="#{acq.Step}" filterBy="#{acq.Step}" filterMatchMode="contains" styleClass="tableTreeText">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{acq.Step}"/>  
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="STATUS" sortBy="#{acq.status}" filterBy="#{acq.status}" styleClass="tableTreeText">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{acq.status}"/>  
                </p:column>  
            </p:dataTable>
```

The bean (onNodeSelect):

```
public void onNodeSelect() {
acqList.clear();
    this.acqList = AcqHelper.getAllViaStartDate(new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
    if (!acqList.isEmpty()) {
        DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("mainForm:acqDataTable");
        dataTable.reset();
        renderTable = true;
  }
```

I don’t want to remove the filter option since its very usable to the client but I don’t know why its blocking the table refresh ??

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: thanks :) - clearFilters() working great

Comment: Just put this thread as the answer, don't forget to mark the post as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to perform changes into a DataTable model. Primefaces is taking data from `#{genRepBean.acqList}`. Just set proper values in that list and reset `#{genRepBean.filteredAcqList}` list. After the request is completed, datatable will be refreshed with new values.